# Subscribing To ThrownExceptions in ReactiveUi

Tags: c#, reactiveui

I am migrating to version 6 of Reactive UI, and am trying to more completely use the tools it provides, namely ThrownExceptions.  Nothing happens when I subscribe to the thrown exceptions property.  I'm sure I'm missing something just not sure what it is right now.

In my simplified example, there is a button with a command bound it it.

```
    public ReactiveCommand<object> Delete { get; private set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Delete = ReactiveCommand.Create();
        Delete.Subscribe(e => CommandExec());
        Delete.ThrownExceptions.Subscribe(ex => HandleException(ex));

    }

    private object HandleException(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Exception Handled");
        return null;
    }

    public IObservable<object> CommandExec()
    {
        throw new Exception("throwing");
    }
```

My assumption is that I would see an "Exception Handled" MessageBox when the exception was thrown.  I'm sure i'm subscribing to something, it's just not clear what it is right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ThrownExceptions` only applies to the background operation declared with `CreateAsyncXYZ`:

```
var someCmd = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncObservable(_ => 
    Observable.Throw<Unit>(new Exception("Oh Noes!"));

someCmd.ThrownExceptions.Subscribe(ex => Console.WriteLine(ex.Message));

await someCmd.ExecuteAsync();
>>> Oh Noes!
```

In ReactiveUI, you should never put Interesting™ code inside the Subscribe block - Subscribe is solely to log the result of operations, or to wire up properties to other properties.

Comment: Firstly, congrats on the "interesting" trademark. Secondly, I was trying to follow the guidelines here https://github.com/reactiveui/rxui-design-guidelines.  Isn't the viewmodel delete command subscribing to clicks and doing "something", while also subscribing to the exceptions that "something" might throw?  Does the something still need to handle its own errors?

Comment: I've proposed a change to the guidelines in this [pull request](https://github.com/reactiveui/rxui-design-guidelines/pull/14) that should help clarify these sort of issues.